# Upload a blob avatar in Octobercms

Tags: vue.js, octobercms, quasar-framework

I'm using October and developping a frontend app in Vue.js (Quasar framework) with JWT Auth.
In Vue, I read a `.jpg` with a FileReader. As a result, I have a blob that I send to `October` with profile parameters with a POST axios request to update an existing user profile.

In October I have a plugin API with the following code in route.php.
It seems I retrieve the blob, but when I try to store it as a `file`, I get inconsistent images stored or October error code like :
[image]

Can I send raw image and how could I store them in October files ? Thanks

```php
    Route::post('Change-Profile', function (Request $request) {
       $user = new User;
       $user->street_addr = $request->street_addr;

       $file = new System\Models\File;
       $file->data = Input::file( $request->avatar );
       $file->is_public = false;
       $file->save();

       $user->avatar = $file;
       $user->save();
```

Comment: can you please share `dump` of the request params

Comment: Hello Hardik, how could I do it ? I tried `dd($request);` or `var_dump($request);` but can't see the result

Comment: ok may be try this `dd(post());`

Comment: Hello Hardik, in my Firefox console, I see the request payload, but it's too long to copy here. Do you want to see the start of the picture field ?

Comment: `dd(post())` shows only the string parameters. In my request payload I get the additionnal blob starting with :
`  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar"; filename="Profil.jpg"
    Content-Type: image/jpeg
    ÿØÿà••JFIF••••••••••ÿÛ••• •••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••( ••%•••!="%)+...••383,7(-.+•`

Comment: hmm then `$user->avatar = Input::file('avatar');`  this should be enough

Comment: Thanks a lot, you save me, I'm driving crazy since 3 days !!!
2 other questions : 1) I try to return the path with `$avatar_path = $user->avatar->getPath();` but it returns a local temp dir : `C:\\Dev\\WinNMP\\tmp` not the final URL to retrieve the pic.
2) I suppose avatar images shouldn't be in a public folder ?

Comment: you need to save it first then only you can get the proper path, as until you save it, it will be in temp.

Comment: Yes fine ! And how could I save the file in protected folder ?
`$file->is_public = false;` is applicable only on the File model

Comment: hmm user->avtar relationship is `public` so maybe you can just extend it and add `privateAvatar` relation and start using it

Comment: check this out for private attachments => https://octobercms.com/docs/database/attachments#file-attachments

Comment: So to be GDPR compliant, I have to extend the model with my privateAvatar.
Many thanks for your precious help !

Comment: sure most welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I spent too much time on this trivial problem, I'd like to share my final solution made with the help of Hardik. Thanks again !

```
        $bIsAvatar = true;
        $user = new User;
        $user_email = $request->email;

        $rules = [
            'email' => 'required|email|min:6',
            'username' => 'required|string|min:5',
            'zip' => 'string|min:1|max:5',
            'avatar' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:10000'
        ];

        $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        if ($validation->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'Error' => 'User : ' . $user_email ,
                'Champs invalides : ' . $validation->messages()
            ], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        $user = User::findByEmail( $user_email );
        if (!$user || $user->isBanned() || !$user->is_activated) {
            return response()->json(
                ['Error' => 'User non trouvé ou non autorisé : ' . $user_email ], Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND
            );
        }

        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->surname = $request->surname;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->street_addr = $request->street_addr;
        $user->city = $request->city;
        $user->zip = $request->zip;
        $user->phone = $request->phone;
        $user->mobile = $request->mobile;
        $user->about_me = $request->about_me;

        if ( $request->avatar == null || empty($request->avatar) ) $bIsAvatar = false;
        else {
            $user->avatar = Input::file('avatar');
            $user->avatar->is_public = false;
        }
        $user->save();
        if ($bIsAvatar) {
            $avatar_path = $user->avatar->getPath();
            //$resultat = "User " . $user->email . " : profil mis à jour avec l'avatar=" . $avatar_path;
            $resultat = "Profil mis à jour avec avatar" . $user;
        } else
            //$resultat = "User : " . $user->email . " : profil mis à jour sans avatar";
            $resultat = "Profil mis à jour sans avatar" . $user;

        return response()->json($resultat);
    });
```